# How do I reformat dates in a CSV to just show MM/YYYY

Tags: python-3.x, date, pandas, reformat

Using Python 3 Pandas, spending an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure out how to take a column of dates from a CSV and make a new column with just MM/YYYY or YYYY/MM/01.

The data looks like Col1 but I am trying to produce Col2:

```
Col1        Col2
2/12/2017   2/1/2017
2/16/2017   2/1/2017
2/28/2017   2/1/2017
3/2/2017    3/1/2017
3/13/2017   3/1/2017
```

Am able to parse the year and month out:

```
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['File_Processed_Date']).month
df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['File_Processed_Date']).year
df['Period'] = df['Month'] + '/' + df['Year']
```

That last line is wrong.  Is there a clever python way to just show 2/2017?

Get the error: "TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

Update, answer by piRsquared:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df.File_Processed_Date)
df['Period'] = d.dt.strftime('%m/1/%Y')
```

This will create a pandas column in a dataframe that converts Col1 into Col2 successfully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

let `d` be just `'Col1'` converted to `Timestamp`

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df.Col1)
```

then

```
d.dt.strftime('%m/1/%Y')

0    02/1/2017
1    02/1/2017
2    02/1/2017
3    03/1/2017
4    03/1/2017
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

---

```
​

d.dt.strftime('%m%Y')

0    02/2017
1    02/2017
2    02/2017
3    03/2017
4    03/2017
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

---

```
d.dt.strftime('%Y/%m/01')

0    2017/02/01
1    2017/02/01
2    2017/02/01
3    2017/03/01
4    2017/03/01
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

---

```
d - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()

0   2017-02-01
1   2017-02-01
2   2017-02-01
3   2017-03-01
4   2017-03-01
Name: Col1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Ah yes! Took me a couple tries but got it: 
d = pd.to_datetime(df.File_Processed_Date) 
df['Period'] = d.dt.strftime('%m/1/%Y') – Arthur D. Howland 7 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [strftime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).